# Cakephp input box validation on ctp page

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I directly input validation as required into input box on ctp file without going to controller or model in Cakephp?

Comment: I was wondering if we could use javascript helper to do this. I have used HTML5 before for validation before but if any other Cake friendly way would help. Thanks

Comment: Try jquery http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate validation plugin. It is not the cake way....

Comment: I think jQuery is good but using HTML5 validation is a better option as it is more SEO friendlier. I have used jQuery validation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), with the Jquery [Validaton plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

It is rather straight foreward to include and write the scripts for.

In the view (using a Users form view for the example)

```
<?php
echo $form->create('User', array('id'=>'UserForm'));
echo $form->input('User.name', array('class'=>'required', 'minlength'=>2));
echo $form->input('User.email', array('class'=>'required email'));
echo $form->end('Send');
echo $javascript->codeBlock('$("#UserForm").validate();', array('inline'=>true));
```

In the layout under the header part

```
echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.6.2.min.js');
echo $javascript->link('jquery.validate.min.js');
```

In the user controller

```
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Javascript');
```

I did testrun the code to confirm it works.